# Problems with accessing DOM tree

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a simple Chrome extension, which should be able to retrieve a DOM nodes and modify them in the specific way. And this is what I'm stuck with.

There are two DOM queries (lets call the A and B) in a javascript file, that i inject in html-page. The first one (A) goes well, but the second one (B) always crushes. Even If I interchange the first (A) query and second one (B), everything will still work in the same way. Query (B) now works as it should in the first place, and A now does nothing.

```
spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

for(j =0 ;j<=divin.length; j++)
{  
    //Manipulations                       //Works just fine 
}


paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for(j =0 ;j<=paragraphs.length; j++)
{  
    //Manipulations                       //Does nothing
}
```

And what we see here. The same code, but different position.

```
paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for(j =0 ;j<=paragraphs.length; j++)
{  
    //Manipulations                      //Works just fine 

}

spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

for(j =0 ;j<=divin.length; j++)
{   
    //Manipulations                     //Does nothing
}
```

I tried every way of injecting this code, but result was always the same.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're using `divin.length` instead of `spans.length`.